# How to map object inheritance to data model?

Tags: sql, database, oop, inheritance

I have an object model with an abstract base class and 5-6 classes inheriting from that base class. I want to design an appropriate relational data model to store them. What is the best way to design the data model?

Here's a quick example for a fictional application that wants to keep track of sent messages:

**Message** (base class)

- long id
- Date creationDate
- String text

**EmailMessage** (extends Message)

- String recipientList

**PhoneMessage** (extends Message)

- String phoneNumber

I tend to create a separate table for every class where each of the tables **email_message** and **phone_message** contains only their private field(s). The beauty of it is that it reflects the object model and keeps a clear separation of concerns. The bad thing is that the data will have to be loaded twice: Once for determining the concrete type and another time to load the remaining data from the concrete table.

I find this to be a very common problem which I haven't found a satisfying answer for. I will be grateful for any of your advice. What are your experiences? Thanks.

Pete

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods to do this, and the choice is up to you.  Common solutions for this are Single Table Inheritance (STI), Multiple Table Inheritance (MTI) also called Class Table Inheritance (CTI), and Concrete Table Inheritance.

With STI, all columns for all subclasses of the parent class are defined in a single table.  Classes that don't make use of certain columns store their values as NULL.  The type for the class is typically stored in an additional column.

With MTI, all superclass columns are stored in a single parent table, while separate tables for each subclass to hold their unique fields.  A foreign key on the subclass tables link back to the parent record.

Concrete Table Inheritance takes this further and requires a completely separate table for each subclass.

There are many articles promoting various methods - STI is usually simplest to implement, while MTI/CTI may avoid certain issues inherent to STI (required nullable fields being a common one).

Comment: +1. The MS EF team did a decent [series of blog posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) about this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped me to find other sources to look at. The clash between OOP and rel. DB is also referred to by **Impedance Mismatch**, if somebody wants to google for it.

I am still curious to know about people's experiences with different approaches. So feel free to continue posting. Thanks.